# Flutter - How to make a FutureBuilder that resolves a Future ImageProvider

Tags: flutter

I'd like to eliminate the boilerplate code used to wait and then replace an ImageProvider placeholder with a final image.

The following works for an Image Widget.

```dart
class FutureImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<Image> futureImage;
  final Image placeholder;

  const FutureImage({Key key, this.futureImage, this.placeholder})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: futureImage,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Image> image) {
        if (image.hasData) {
          return image.data; 
        } else {
          return placeholder; 
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

However I need an ImageProvider (because it can be used in places where an Image cannot)

The following doesn't work because ImageProvider isn't a Widget:

```dart
class FutureImageProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<ImageProvider> futureImageProvider;
  final ImageProvider placeholder;

  const FutureImageProvider(
      {Key key, this.futureImageProvider, this.placeholder})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: futureImageProvider,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ImageProvider> image) {
        if (image.hasData) {
          return image.data; 
        } else {
          return placeholder; 
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: Atthe moment I use a Statefull widget with an initState which will replace the placeholder with the final ImageProvider once it is resolved.

I'd like a widget that can do that and be generic to use in many places without having to code the exact same initState over and over.

Comment: Actually now I realise I already have a widget.  In 90% of the cases I have a BoxDecoration that uses the ImageProvider. I can wrap the outer widget of the BoxDecoration and let it accept an ImageProvider!  Thank you, your question solved the issue.

Comment: well, i haven't thought my question was so inspiring :-)

Comment: Absolutely got me to think in the right direction.

Comment: nice to hear it, take care...